# A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored

Tags: spring-security

I am running into this issue with Spring 3.1.3 release and with the following application context file. I am not quite sure why does this occur. Have looked into most of the posts related to this. I dont think I have a version mismatch.

Application Context file:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http auto-config='true' entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/panelpipeline/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
</security:http>

<bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
    <property name="service"
        value="https://seqdws1/cas/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
    <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
</bean>

<security:http entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER"
        ref="casFilter" />
</security:http>

<bean id="casFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="casEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginUrl" value="https://seqdws1/cas/login" />
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService" />
    <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
    <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://seqdws1/cas" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only" />
</bean>

<security:user-service id="userService">
    <security:user name="joe" password="joe" authorities="ROLE_USER" />     
</security:user-service>

<!-- <security:authentication-manager> <security:authentication-provider> 
    <security:user-service> <security:user name="jimi" password="jimispassword" 
    authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" /> <security:user name="bob" password="bobspassword" 
    authorities="ROLE_USER" /> </security:user-service> </security:authentication-provider> 
    </security:authentication-manager> -->
```

POM dependencies

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>${gwtVersion}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <classifier>sources</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The configuration you've posted has two `<http>` elements, neither of which has a `pattern` attribute so both are implicitly defined to match all requests. The second one will overwrite the first.

That doesn't necessarily explain why you are seeing this message (since it should normally apply to filters within a single chain), but it is definitely a mistake.

You should also probably remove `auto-config='true'` unless you know for sure that you want the extra filters which it implicitly adds.

Comment: ah..That worked after removing the duplicate <http> element. Now my application goes to the CAS SSO page. But after the authentication, i get an error "This webpage has a redirect loop". I have my CAS running on a different server.