# Multiple <http> tags with same authentication manager in Spring Security 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.1.2
This version allows multiple "http" tags.

I have an application that has two separate login pages, one for user and another for admin. Both of them will use the same authentication manager.

I have build my spring-security.xml in the following manner

```
<sec:http pattern="/loginForm.jsp" security="none"/>
            <sec:http pattern="/loginForm2.jsp" security="none"/>
            <sec:http auto-config="true">
                <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login1*" access="ROLE_USER" />
                <sec:form-login login-page="/loginForm.jsp" default-target-url="/login1"
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginForm.jsp?login_error=1" />
                <sec:logout logout-success-url="/loginForm.jsp" />
            </sec:http>

            <sec:http auto-config="true">
                <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login2*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <sec:form-login login-page="/loginForm2.jsp" default-target-url="/login2"
                    authentication-failure-url="/loginForm2.jsp?login_error=1" />
                <sec:logout logout-success-url="/loginForm2.jsp" />
            </sec:http>



<sec:authentication-manager>
               <sec:authentication-provider>
                   <sec:user-service>
                         <sec:user name="qwertyui" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                         <sec:user name="asdfghjk" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                   </sec:user-service>
               </sec:authentication-provider>

            </sec:authentication-manager>
```

But I am getting this error "A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your  namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration"

If I omit any one of the  tag, it works fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A universal match pattern ('/\*\*') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818719/a-universal-match-pattern-is-defined-before-other-patterns-in-the-filter)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the pattern attribute on your http element, your http stanza will default to /**, which is a universal match pattern.

I made this mistake myself, because I thought it was only considering the "intercept-url" elements, and none of my intercept-url elements defined a universal match pattern.

Make sure all of your http elements have a pattern attribute defined.

Answer (score 0):

http tag creates security filter chain, default is /**, since you have two of  with same default pattern, hence the error, Makes sense, how would spring build filter chains. its duplicate.