# Error defining with multiple HTTP elements Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to have two separate login pages for 2 separate sections inside my application, so I've added a new http element to the security-context.xml file as instructed by the Spring security documentation but I am getting the following error whenever I try to run the applications:

> A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in
>   the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the
>   ordering in your  namespace or FilterChainProxy bean
>   configuration

Here is my security-context.xml file:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        default-target-url="/admin/dashboard" always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/login/?error_msg=wrong username or password" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')" />       
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
</security:http>

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:form-login login-page="/customer-portal/login"
        default-target-url="/customer-portal/dashboard" always-use-default-target="true"
        authentication-failure-url="/customer-portal/login/?error_msg=wrong username or password" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/customer-portal/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />      
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/customer-portal/login"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="userServiceImpl">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

After searching the web, I found some recommendations to remove auto-config, tried it but it didn't work...so I was wondering if anyone can please tell me what I am missing here and how to solve this error?

Thanks

Comment: Your search should have led you to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14876646/241990) which explains your problem. Just type the complete error message into the search box. The first sentence explains the problem. The recommendation to remove `auto-config` is coincidental but a good idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A universal match pattern ('/\*\*') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818719/a-universal-match-pattern-is-defined-before-other-patterns-in-the-filter)

Comment: @LukeTaylor I don't think my problem is simillar to those 2 you pointed out. I have two login pages, one for admin section, the other for customers-portal, each has their own tables in DB, so the reason I am adding the other http element is not to protect another folder under admin but rather to protect a different section in the app. So I need to protect the admin/ folder and all of its subs, so I added admin/** and customers-portal/ and all of its subs so I added customers-portal/**

Comment: Please read it again... you have two http blocks, neither of which has a 'pattern' attribute, hence you will get that error. You can't apply two different filter chains to all requests. You need to specialize at least one of them.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you have two `http` blocks, each of which has `/**` pattern, causing a conflict - you can only apply one filter chain to a request.

Try changing your first `http` block to use

```
<security:http pattern="/admin/**" use-expressions="true">
```

which will only apply that filter chain to requests matching that path, and will remove the conflict.