# Spring Security Form Login Not Identified

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security

I'm having to migrate an application from Spring Security 2 to 3.2 and I'm completely lost, I've never used spring security :(

I modified some configurations on spring-security.xml:

```
<http pattern="/ordreminderform.jsp" security="none" />
<http pattern="/passwordreminder.jsp" security="none" />
<http pattern="/getUser.jsp" security="none" />
<http pattern="/csra2.css" security="none" />
<http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied.jsp">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_B1,ROLE_B2,ROLE_B3" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/Users.do" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/Project.do"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_B1,ROLE_B2,ROLE_B3" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/Csra.do"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_B1,ROLE_B2,ROLE_B3" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/About.do"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_B1,ROLE_B2,ROLE_B3" />

    <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </session-management>

    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?login_error=true"
        username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
        default-target-url="/index.jsp" always-use-default-target="true" />

</http>

<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/usuarios/**"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_B1,ROLE_B2,ROLE_B3" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <!--<intercept-url pattern="/**" -->
    <!-- access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_B1,ROLE_B2,ROLE_B3" /> -->
</http>

<http pattern="/imagens/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
<http pattern="/fonts/**" security="none" />
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_B1,ROLE_B2,ROLE_B3" />
</http>
```

When I try to deploy it, it throws:

```
                     org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration      problem:No AuthenticationEntryPoint could be established. Please make sure you have a login mechanism configured through the namespace (such as form-login) or specify a custom AuthenticationEntryPoint with the 'entry-point-ref' attribute |Offending resource: class path resource [spring-security-config.xml]
```

It's weird because I do have a form-login! The .xml is a mess and I'm trying to make it better.  I'm using Spring* 3.1.0 and Spring Security 3.2.3

Thanks!

Comment: What is in the "other <http>....</http>" bit you haven't posted?

Comment: Added the other http now. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three `<http>` blocks which are creating three *separate* security filter chains (i.e. where you aren't using `security='none'` to bypass security for particular URLs).

Neither of these has a "pattern" attribute which means they will both be configured to handle all requests, which doesn't make sense. The second and third of these blocks have no authentication method configured. Either of these would cause the error you are getting. The `form-login` only applies with the `http` element which contains it.

Just use one `<http>` element to contain all the `intercept-url` configurations you want to apply, unless you specifically want to have different security configurations for different URL patterns.

Also take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211563/error-defining-with-multiple-http-elements-spring-security/21233742#21233742).

Comment: Thanks, Luke! After a bit more documentation reading I realized it. I wasn't getting the point of the spring way of doing it. It's a way different from Rails. :)