# Spring security Multiple Login Filters Error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to integrate spring security with my existing spring project. My requirement is one user should be able to login with oAuth and another user should be able to login with LDAP. For this i have included two custom filters. Here is my code.

```
    <bean:bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        id="tenant2FormLoginFilter"
        class="com.packtpub.springsecurity.web.authentication.TenantUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login2"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="usernameParameter" value="un"/>
    <property name="passwordParameter" value="pw"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/default"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login/form?error"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean:bean>
```

and as custom filters should be mentioned under http block, i want to mention both custom filters as "FORM_LOGIN_FILTER". I want to mention like below

```
<http use-expressions="true"
        entry-point-ref="loginEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter ref="tenant1FormLoginFilter"
            position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout"
            logout-success-url="/login/form?logout"/>
</http>

<http use-expressions="true"
        entry-point-ref="loginEntryPoint">

    <custom-filter ref="tenant2FormLoginFilter"
            position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout"
            logout-success-url="/login/form?logout"/>
</http>
```

but when i am trying to run the project it is giving below error

```
    A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the 
    filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your     
    <security:http>namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
```

when i give only one http block with one custom filter it is working fine. but i am getting error only when i am giving multiple http blocks(which is correct as we cannot give multiple http blocks with same pattern) or multiple custom filters with same position "FORM_LOGIN_FILTER". Please give any suggestions how to use multiple filters with same position "FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" and same http pattern.

Comment: You can't have two `<http/>` elements with the same request matcher (yours both have the default matcher). You said "one user can do X", so how would you decide which authentication channel to use? Maybe there's a signature in the requests (like a different path)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A universal match pattern ('/\*\*') is defined before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818719/a-universal-match-pattern-is-defined-before-other-patterns-in-the-filter)

Comment: ya i understood that but i want to use two custom filters with same provider "FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" for the same http block which i am not able to do. Please give any suggestions for this.

Comment: @Raghavendra - is this still an issue?

Comment: @avijendr yes.. My Actual Problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252799/spring-security-oauth-ldap-integration-for-multitenant-application  (refer this link). For solving this requirement i am trying in different ways. I am still not able to solve