# Spring Security - OAuth, LDAP Integration for multitenant application

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, ldap, multi-tenant

I am using spring security for my spring multitenant application. I am using spring security 3.2

I am using spring security for my spring multitenant application. My requirement 
is tenant1 should be authorized against oauth and tenant2 should be authorized 
against ldap and tenant3 should be authorized against database. I will be knowing 
the authorization method for the tenant through properties file. I am able to 
authorize user against any single authorization method. But i am not able to 
configure for multiple authorization methods. Please someone give any suggestions
on this.

Comment: have you got any solution on this?

Comment: Yes. But we had to use different url's for each tenant. eg: tenant1.domain.com, tenant2.domain.com @Kamini

Answer (score -1):

In case of web application, you can use different login URLs and allow user to choose authentication method. Then separate security filters should be applied for each URL.
You can check this configuration: https://code.google.com/p/opendatakit/source/browse/eclipse-aggregate-gae/war/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml?repo=aggregate